# Multiple file.line in single state in Salt

Tags: salt-stack

I would like to have a Salt state for managing my SSH file. This requires multiple `file.line` operations. How can I do this?

**UPDATE: See bottom of the question for my current workaround**

What I have is this:

```
Secure SSH:
  file:
   - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   - line:
     - match: "^PasswordAuthentication "
     - content: "PasswordAuthentication no"
     - mode: ensure
   - line:
     - match: "^PubkeyAuthentication "
     - content: "PubkeyAuthentication yes"
     - mode: ensure
   - line:
     - match: "^Port "
     - content: "Port 8888"
     - mode: ensure
  service.running:
    - name: sshd
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

but this fails with

```
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    No function declared in state 'file' in SLS u'xyz'
```

Actually my first attempt was this:

```
Secure SSH:
  file.line:
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - match: "^PasswordAuthentication "
    - content: "PasswordAuthentication no"
    - mode: ensure
  file.line:
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - match: "^PubkeyAuthentication "
    - content: "PubkeyAuthentication yes"
    - mode: ensure
  file.line:
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - match: "^Port "
    - content: "Port 8888"
    - mode: ensure
  service.running:
    - name: sshd
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

but this fails with

```
    Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:xyz' failed: Conflicting ID 'file.line'
```

I understand this error because every state function is a dictionary key, but it does look very clean.

The Salt documentation is very unhelpful in this because it does not say **anything** about what to do when just **maybe** you want to modify multiple things to one file, and it conveniently only gives very trivial examples in its documentation.

**UPDATE:**
I got it to work by using a separate state for each line (and I also changed `file.line` to `file.replace` but that was another issue). I think this is rather unwieldy plus isn't the service reloaded after every step?

```
Disallow SSH password authentication:
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - pattern: ^PasswordAuthentication .*
    - repl: PasswordAuthentication no
    - append_if_not_found: True
  service.running:
    - name: sshd
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Allow SSH public key authentication:
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - pattern: ^PubkeyAuthentication .*
    - repl: PubkeyAuthentication yes
    - append_if_not_found: True
  service.running:
    - name: sshd
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Set SSH port:
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - pattern: ^Port .*
    - repl: Port 8888
    - append_if_not_found: True
  service.running:
    - name: sshd
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Answer (score 3):

Separating the file.replace to multiple states is the way to go.

To avoid redundancy you should move the service.running to its own state as well. Plus: when using watch (or watch_in) you'll need to specify the name of state you are watching after the `file:` part.

The result will look like this:

```
Disallow SSH password authentication:
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - pattern: ^PasswordAuthentication .*
    - repl: PasswordAuthentication no
    - append_if_not_found: True
    - watch_in:
      - service: ssh_service

Allow SSH public key authentication:
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - pattern: ^PubkeyAuthentication .*
    - repl: PubkeyAuthentication yes
    - append_if_not_found: True
    - watch_in:
      - service: ssh_service

Set SSH port:
  file.replace:
    - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    - pattern: ^Port .*
    - repl: Port 8888
    - append_if_not_found: True
    - watch_in:
      - service: ssh_service

ssh_service:
  service.running:
    - name: sshd
```

Answer (score 2):

1. I would recommend checking out `listen` instead of `watch`.  Watch will restart sshd 3 times, once after each time the file is changed.

   If you use listen, it will only restart it once at the very end.  But you have to do
2. Put the `service.running` at the very end with it's own stateid and listen to all of the changes.

   ```
   Disallow SSH password authentication:
     file.replace:
       - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
       - pattern: ^PasswordAuthentication .*
       - repl: PasswordAuthentication no
       - append_if_not_found: True

   Allow SSH public key authentication:
     file.replace:
       - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
       - pattern: ^PubkeyAuthentication .*
       - repl: PubkeyAuthentication yes
       - append_if_not_found: True

   Set SSH port:
     file.replace:
       - name: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
       - pattern: ^Port .*
       - repl: Port 8888
       - append_if_not_found: True

   Start SSHD:
     service.running:
       - name: sshd
       - listen:
         - file: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
   ```
3. You might also find it worthwhile to check out the [augeas](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.augeas.html) state.  It makes making changes like this a lot easier and look better in the state files.

   ```
   sshd_config:
     augeas.change:
       - context: /files/etc/ssh/sshd_config
       - changes:
         - set Port 8888
         - set PasswordAuthentication yes
         - set PubkeyAuthentication yes
     service.running:
       - name: sshd
       - listen:
         - augeas: sshd_config
   ```